In app purchase - subscription with possibly different amounts each time
I have an app in which users (content providers) can create their channel and post material and build their own subscriber base for that channel. The app is free for readers, but not for the content providers.
For content providers:
As long as they have less than 1000 subscribers, it is free for them.
For additional subscribers, they have to pay X cents per subscriber per month. Obviously, the subscriber base may increase/decrease each month.
So, if at the end of Month m, they have 5000 subscribers, they need to pay for 4000 subscribers to be able to continue to post material.
The next month, they may have increased their subscriber base to 7320, in which case they will have to pay for 6320 subscribers for that month and so on.
How do I model this within the in_app_purchase scheme of things?
Thanks
